# Pfeiffer 3.1 random variable exercise solution verification

Tags: probability-theory, solution-verification, random-variables

I am self teaching through Pfeiffer's Concepts of Probability Theory and want to make sure I understand this basic exercise on Random Variables. This is exercise 3.1 . Does this solution look correct?

Suppose $X(\cdot)$ is a simple random variable given by

$X(\cdot) = I_A(\cdot) - 4I_B(\cdot) + 2I_C(\cdot) + 5I_D(\cdot)$

where $\{A,B,C,D\}$ is a partition of the whole space $S$.

(a) What is the range of $X(\cdot)$

Since $\{A,B,C,D\}$ form a partition of $S$, for any $\xi \in S$, exactly one of the indicators functions will have a value of 1 and all the others a value of 0. Thus the range of $X(\cdot)$ is $\{-4,1,2,5\}$

(b) Express in terms of members of the partition the set $X^{-1}(M)$ where

(1) $M = (0,1)$

Since there are no values in the range between 0 and 1 exclusive, the reverse image is the empty set, i.e. the null event.

(2) $M= \{-1,3,5\}$

Since the only element of the range of $X(\cdot)$ in $M$ is 5, and $X(\xi) = 5$ only for those $\xi \in D$ since $I_D$ is paired with 5 in $X(\cdot)$,  $X^{-1}(M) = D$

(3) $M= (-\infty,4]$

Similarly, since this interval contains the entire range of $X(\cdot)$ other than 5, $X^{-1}(M) = D^c$

(4) $M = (2, \infty)$

The only value of the range of $X(\cdot)$ in $M$ is 5 so $X^{-1}(M) = D$

Comment: Seems correct to me

Comment: Thanks for looking it over. I appreciate it.